# Collectstatic creates empty files

Tags: python, django, django-storage

I'm trying to upgrade an app to Django 1.11, but experience issues with `collectstatic`.

Old versions:

```
django 1.8.17 
django-storages 1.5.1
```

New versions:

```
django 1.11.12
django-storages 1.6.6
```

Storage:

```
class StaticS3BotoStorage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    location = 'static'
    file_overwrite = True
    preload_metadata = True
```

or

```
class StaticS3BotoStorage(CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    location = 'static'
    file_overwrite = True
    preload_metadata = True
```

With the old versions, `collectstatic` worked fine, including `collectstatic --clear`.

After the upgrade, `collectstatic --clear` fails (no files are deleted).
`collectstatic` does copy files, however, sometimes it creates two versions of the same file. In this particular example, I get `base.hash1.css` and `base.hash2.css`. `base.hash2.css` is empty, so the pages open, but do not render correctly.

If I don't use `CachedFilesMixin` or `ManifestFilesMixin`, `collectstatic` works fine, but clear still fails.

I tested different combinations of django 1.11 and django-storages, but they all seem to behave the same.

Did someone else experience a similar issue?

Answer (score 5):

We've encountered the same issue.

The underlying problem, I think, has multiple issues / sources:

- The ManifestFilesMixin uses and reuses ContentFile objects for generating the hashed files and saves them multiple times. Without resetting the ContentFile objects (by calling .seek(0) on them).
- The S3BotoStorage saves these files, without checking if they are at the correct position. Compare this to FileSystemStorage: The files are always read through from the beginning by iterating over the .chuncks() of the file.

We worked around the empty-file-issue by overriding S3BotoStorage like this:

```
class PatchedS3StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def _save(self, name, content):
        if hasattr(content, 'seek') and hasattr(content, 'seekable') and content.seekable():
            content.seek(0)
        return super()._save(name, content)
```

In short, we seek to the beginning of the file before saving it.

Comment: I could make collectstatic work with boto3, but media upload then failed (actually not upload, but thumbnail creation). So the intermediary solution was to use boto3 for static, boto for media/thumbnails. 

However, due to memory issues (described here: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/95), we had to stop using django-storages in the end. We have many thumbnails and it was eating too much memory.

Comment: Thankyou for this @hellphil ! I had the same problem and adapted this answer to use `boto3` (using `boto` with the above answer lead to other strange issues with additional files being uploaded to S3 erroneously). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309821/collectstatic-incorrectly-creates-multiple-css-files-in-s3/52323409#52323409